# ReactJS onChange prevent user keep typing

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way where you can stop user typing when the words limits exceeds.

At the moment i have onChange in a `textarea` and `e.preventDefault();`. However it doesn't seems to stop users from typing. is there anyway can achieve this, i know you can `addEventlister` for `keypress` and prevent the default. but how does reactJS achieve the same functionality?

In jQuery: (how do i achieve the same in reactJS)?

```
  $(function(){
    $('textarea').keypress(function() {
      var l = $(this).val().split(' ');
      if(l.length > 50){
        return false;
      }
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In react you can use `onKeyPress` event and use `.preventDefault`, `.stopPropagation` methods, like this

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    handleKeyPress: function(e) {
        var value = e.currentTarget.value.split(' ');

        if (value.length > 10) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            console.log(value);
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return <textarea onKeyPress={ this.handleKeyPress }></textarea>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/3v875fkL/)

`return false` from within a `jQuery` event handler is effectively the same as calling both `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation`

Comment: wow completely missed that... Forgot to say thank you for the answer.

Comment: Deprecated, need to use onKeyUp now.

Answer (score 1):

What about `<textarea maxLength={10}/>` ?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp